# Reshaping multidimensional array to 2-D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape

I have a 4-D array `a` where `a.shape = (300, 300, 40, 193)`

I want to reshape it to shape (40, 300*300*193).

So, after the reshape, `new_a[0,:]` should be equivalent to `a[:,:,0,:].ravel()`

What is proper way to use `numpy.reshape` to do this?

Comment: You need to `transpose` first: try `a.transpose((2,0,1,3)).reshape(40,-1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use [`np.rollaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html). Roll axis number 2 to be in front of axis number 0, then reshape.

```
a = np.rollaxis(a, 2, 0)
a = a.reshape((40, 300*300*193))
```

Here's a smaller version for demonstration:

```
>>> a = np.random.randn(30, 30, 40, 19)
>>> b = np.rollaxis(a, 2, 0)
>>> b = b.reshape((40, 30*30*19))
>>> (b[0, :] == a[:, :, 0, :].ravel()).all()
True
```

Answer (score -1):

why you don't just do:

```
a.reshape([a.shape[2], a.shape[0]*a.shape[1]*a.shape[3]])
a.shape #(40, 17370000)
```

Comment: The shape will be correct, but the elements won't be. What you wrote is just `a.reshape(a.shape[2],-1)`, but incorrect. Compare the test that OP wrote: `new_a[0,:]` vs `a[:,:,0,:].ravel()`; I don't think these are the same for the above.

Comment: you re right. actually your solution `a.transpose((2,0,1,3)).reshape(40,-1)` seems the intended!